# Passing IP address isn't working in a Function, unless I explicitly mention it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the Country name for the given IP address using the 'GeoIP2-City.mmdb' file.

Ex: IP: 24.171.221.56, I need to get 'Puerto Rico'. But this isn't working when I passed the IP address in a function.

```
ipa = ['24.171.221.56']

def country(ipa, reader):
    try:
        response = reader.city(ipa)
        response = response.country.name
        return response
    except:
        return 'NA'

country(ipa, reader=geoip2.database.Reader('GeoIP2-City.mmdb'))

'NA'
```

However, If I use the actual IP address in the function it is returning 'Puerto Rico'

```
ipa = ['24.171.221.56']

def country(ipa, reader):
    try:
        response = reader.city('24.171.221.56')
        response = response.country.name
        return response
    except:
        return 'NA'

country(ipa, reader=geoip2.database.Reader('GeoIP2-City.mmdb'))

'Puerto Rico'
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code snippet.

**Code:**

```
import geoip2.database as ip_db


ip_list = ['24.171.221.56', '81.212.104.158', '90.183.159.46']

def country(ip_list, reader):
  country_dict = {}
  for ip in ip_list:
    try:
        response = reader.city(ip)
        country = response.country.name
        country_dict[ip] = country
    except:
        country_dict[ip] = 'NA'
  return country_dict

print(country(ip_list, reader=ip_db.Reader('GeoIP2-City.mmdb')))
```

**Output:**

```
{'24.171.221.56': 'Puerto Rico', '81.212.104.158': 'Turkey', '90.183.159.46': 'Czechia'}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to pass the ip as a string, not as a list, since your function is only designed to return the location of one IP:

```
ip = '24.171.221.56'
```

Second, it should be `ip`, not `ipa`. Your function argument must match the variable you're using inside it, and the argument you send must match what you've defined outside. It's best to standardize them all to `ip`.

```
ip = '24.171.221.56'

def country(ip, reader):
    try:
        response = reader.city(ip)
        response = response.country.name
        return response
    except:
        return 'NA'

country(ip, reader=geoip2.database.Reader('GeoIP2-City.mmdb'))
```

If you were intending to do this for multiple ips, you can define them in a list, but then you have to call the function once for each item in the list:

```
reader=geoip2.database.Reader('GeoIP2-City.mmdb')
ips=['24.171.221.56','24.171.221.57']
for ip in ips:
    country(ip, reader=reader)
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass a list to the function, so you need to do ip[0] or change it inside the function to use lists

Answer (score 1):

In line:

```
response = reader.city(ip)
```

ip is not defined.